# DataTable não filtra apos pegar valor do select

Tags: jquery-datatables

Estou tendo seguinte problema, apos pegar o valor do select não consigo filtrar o datatable

```
$('#genero_candidato, #area_interesse1_candidato').change(function() {

  var genero = $('#genero_candidato').val();
  var area = $('#area_interesse1_candidato').val();

  $.each(listcandidatos, function(i, field) {
    var teste = field.data_nasc_candidato.split("-");
    var data1 = idade(teste[0], teste[1], teste[2]) + " Anos";
    if (field.genero_candidato == genero && field.area_interesse1_candidato == area) {
      $('#mostrarDados').append('<tr><td><a href="<?= base_url(); ?>Lista/mostrarCandidato/' + field.id_candidato + '">' + field.nome_candidato + '</a></td>' +
                                '<td><a href="<?= base_url(); ?>Lista/mostrarCandidato/' + field.id_candidato + '">' + field.proposta_candidato + '</a></td>' +
                                '<td><a href="<?= base_url(); ?>Lista/mostrarCandidato/' + field.id_candidato + '">' + data1 + '</a></td></tr>');
    }
    if (genero == "" && field.area_interesse1_candidato == area) {
      $('#mostrarDados').append('<tr><td><a href="<?= base_url(); ?>Lista/mostrarCandidato/' + field.id_candidato + '">' + field.nome_candidato + '</a></td>' +
                                '<td><a href="<?= base_url(); ?>Lista/mostrarCandidato/' + field.id_candidato + '">' + field.proposta_candidato + '</a></td>' +
                                '<td><a href="<?= base_url(); ?>Lista/mostrarCandidato/' + field.id_candidato + '">' + data1 + '</a></td></tr>');
    }
    if (field.genero_candidato == genero && area == "") {
      $('#mostrarDados').append('<tr><td><a href="<?= base_url(); ?>Lista/mostrarCandidato/' + field.id_candidato + '">' + field.nome_candidato + '</a></td>' +
                                '<td><a href="<?= base_url(); ?>Lista/mostrarCandidato/' + field.id_candidato + '">' + field.proposta_candidato + '</a></td>' +
                                '<td><a href="<?= base_url(); ?>Lista/mostrarCandidato/' + field.id_candidato + '">' + data1 + '</a></td></tr>');
    }
    if (genero == "" && area == "") {
      $('#mostrarDados').append('<tr><td><a href="<?= base_url(); ?>Lista/mostrarCandidato/' + field.id_candidato + '">' + field.nome_candidato + '</a></td>' +
                                '<td><a href="<?= base_url(); ?>Lista/mostrarCandidato/' + field.id_candidato + '">' + field.proposta_candidato + '</a></td>' +
                                '<td><a href="<?= base_url(); ?>Lista/mostrarCandidato/' + field.id_candidato + '">' + data1 + '</a></td></tr>');
    }

  });


});
```

Comment: Mas, pq vc está montando uma tabela, não seria mais fácil só inserir os dados no Datatable?

Comment: Os dados já estão no datatable, o que eu queria era filtrar os dados. por exemplo: genero queria pegar apenas masculino, mas no datatable ele não fica apenas os masculino, fica todos os dados

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver usando destroy() do datatable;

Comment: Tem como mostrar o código que resolveu o problema? onde exatamente vc colocou o `destroy()` [edit] a resposta detalhando um pouco mais ;)